# Dirichlet boundary condition for Green function convolution in Fourier domain

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, fft, dirichlet

I am currently working on the heat diffusion equation in 3D in python.

I am resolving the heat diffusion equation with the convolution of the Green function of this equation with a source equation, which becomes a multiplication into a Fourier domain.

G * S ---> TF --- > G x S

Because of my use of Fourier transform, I have boundary conditions, which implies secondary sources all around my 3D space of simulation.

[image]

I would like, in order to negate the impact of those secondary imaginary sources, to apply Dirichlet boundary condition, which would apply a 0 value at the edges, and stop the diffusion of heat back to my area of interest.

Have you done it yet ? Do you have an idea of how to code and implement that ? Maybe there is another way to negate those issues ?

Thank you !

Comment: This is much less a programming question than it is about math / applied math (physics).

Comment: Yes, definitively. But I think I understood the applied maths question. I really have trouble figuring how to implement it into my script.

Answer (score 0):

Your mathematical problem as it is hard, but your numpy problem not so much:

so, assuming you have a three-dimensional `numpy.ndarray`, you get three indices; so you just set all these boundaries to 0:

```
arr[:,0,0] = 0 # all x, y == z == 0
arr[0,:,0] = 0 # all y, x == z == 0
arr[0,0,:] = 0 # all z, x == y == 0

arr[:,-1,0] = 0 # all x, y == last, z = 0
...

arr[:,-1,-1] = 0 # all x, y == z == last
```

Comment: Hi ! 
Thank you for your help.
What you propose, I have already tried to do it. Yes it works for boundaries, but in no case it stops the thing of imaginary sources. It does just force the value to be 0 at borders.

I would need something more sophisticated, like maybe anti sources, to block the heat back.

Comment: @Magea anti-sources are sinks :D no, since all the surrounding areas are absolutely identical to the one you are considering, and you enforce 0 on the boundary of that, you enforce 0 on all boundaries, so there can't be diffusion back into your cell. What you're doing seems to have mathematical kinks. What about applying a rectangular (ok, in three dimensions, cubic) window to your field before fourier transform? `F{(G*S)W} = F{W}F{G*S}`. The fourier transform of a rectangular window is the `sinc` function.

Comment: @Magea of course, that would only apply to your continuous mathematical considerations, and not to your simulation (`sinc` having infinite carrier and all); but it illustrates the important fact that if you need to simulate a field, and you need things to be non-periodic, you will need to apply a window, and you will need to chose both a window and a "safe" padding area large enough to sufficiently suppress the effects of the side lobes of the sinc you inherently get when rectangularly windowing your data (which is what you do when you set 0 around it).

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, 1) I may have poorly tried yesterday to do what you first suggested me, and I should try again because it should be OK  2) I did not think of that, it could be interesting.  I am going to try that too
Thanks !

Comment: Müller So I tried both options. In the two cases,  achieved to obtain the "0 windowed" area all around my place of simulation. It did not solve the problem at all ...
I really think I ave to go deeper with Dirichlet conditions into my equations ...